# How to use default logger and custom logger in django but avoid duplicate logs

Tags: python, django, logging

I have two sets of APIs in a Django project that I want to use my custom logger. So in every viewset I will be doing `logger.info(...)` or `logger.error(...)` before the responses.

Everywhere else in the project, like Admin pages and other tools, I'd like to leave the logging as it is for now.

This is how I have defined my `LOGGING` in settings.py.

```
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'formatters': {
        'standard': {
            'format':
                'ts=%(asctime)s level=%(levelname)s caller=%(filename)s:%(funcName)s:%(lineno)s %(message)s',
            'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',
        },
    },
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
            'formatter': 'standard',
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'my_logger': {
            'handlers': ['console'],
            'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO'),
            'propagate': False,
        },
    },
}
```

In my views I am calling the logger like:

```py
logger = logging.getLogger('my_logger')
logger.info("Some message")
```

The problem is that the way it is, the logging in the APIs is duplicated for every request, my logger and the existing django logger. How can I "disable" the default django logger in the APIs but keep it everywhere else?

Example of duplicated logs:

```bash
ts=2022-06-07 09:50:14 level=INFO caller=views.py:retrieve:450 path=/api/v1/<path>/<uuid>/ method=GET status=200 user=71 msg=Some message
[07/Jun/2022 09:50:14] "GET /api/v1/<path>/<uuid>/ HTTP/1.1" 200 41633
```

Answer (score 1):

You have called your custom logger `django`. The `django` logger is a root logger which catches all logs, unless child loggers are configured with the keyword `"propagate": False`. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#default-logging-conditions. If you give it a different name, then you can log to that logger directly, e.g.

```
    'loggers': {
        'my_custom_logger': {
            'propagate': False,
            # other properties here
        }
    }
```

In your view, use

```
logger = logging.getLogger("my_custom_logger")
logger.ERROR("foo")
```

These log messages should not propagate to the default logger.

---

Seeing your updated question, you could disable the default `django.server` logger entries for the API URL paths by adding a Filter object. See https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#filter-objects and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#filters: if the Filter's `.filter()` method returns `0` or `False` for a given log record, it will not be logged.

Comment: I realized that later on. I'm now using a custom name for my logger but even with `propagate: False` I get duplicate entries in the logging. I will update my post with an example

Comment: The duplicate log entry example you give doesn't look like a duplicate. It's two different entries logged from two different code paths. The `GET` row seems to come from the `django.server` logger, see the formatting matching the default config at https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/utils/log.py#L32,  documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/logging/#django-server, and where it's loaded at https://github.com/django/django/blob/4.0/django/core/servers/basehttp.py#L24

Comment: They are from the same path, logged in the same request from two different loggers. So if I understood correctly one is from my explicit call of `logger.info(...)` and the other from `django.server` logger

Comment: Same URL path, yes, but a different code path. One is from the wsgi server, here likely Django's runserver command, which handles the request and sends it to the right view function, and the other is from your views module. I've added a suggestion to my answer for how to filter out the `django.server` logger for those URL paths. I'm not familiar with the format of the log entry sent to that Filter object, so you will have to inspect there and experiment.

Answer (score 0):

It should be enough to change the configuration to something like

```
'loggers': {
    'django': {
        'level': 'CRITICAL'
    },
    'my_logger': {
        'handlers': ['console'],
        'level': os.getenv('DJANGO_LOG_LEVEL', 'INFO')
    },
},
```

because then all Django packages/modules should not output anything (other than `CRITICAL` stuff). You don't need a `propagate` setting since you haven't configured any handlers for the root logger (the parent of the `my_logger` logger) - `propagate` would only control whether parent loggers' handlers are asked to handle an event, and in this case there would be no such handlers.

Comment: But I want the Django packages to output logs (even info level logs) using `my_logger`. But I don't want these packages to log in the places that I explicitly call `logger.info(...)` like in the APIs views.

Comment: @everspader That won't happen - Django packages log to loggers named 'django' or 'django.XXX'.

Comment: Yeah, I realized that. Do you know how if I can apply a filter at the logger level instead of the handler so that for example, all requests in `/api/` path use only `my_logger` and `django` 's logger is ignored?